# Pipeline failed at model evaluation stage : ClientError: Cannot access S3 key: bucket//evaluation.json

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pipeline

I am creating model pipeline. At model evaluation processing job succeeded. However, the pipeline step of the specific processing job failed. The error message is `ClientError: Cannot access S3 key: bucket//evaluation.json`

The searching of the error, it seem The pipeline role (not the job role) could not read the s3 key.

Could you help me add add policy that allows access to all the resources from bucket.

I expect guidlines how to add policy to pipelines.